# White square when keyboard dismiss

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, keyboard, dropdown

I made a form to register a trip, it works, that's cool. But when I want to use the keyboard and then dismiss it, it leaves a white space on the bottom of page (as you can see next)

[image]
[image]

I don't really get where it goes wrong... I thought maybe it was ondropdownshow or ondropdownclose but it doesn't seem to be there.

```
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../assets/images/background.jpg")}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <Header
          backgroundImage={require("../../assets/images/bg-header.png")}
          centerComponent={{
            text: i18n.t("tripsform.title").toUpperCase(),
            style: styles.headerComponentStyle
          }}
          containerStyle={styles.headerContainerStyle}
          statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
        />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.myForm}>
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.autocompletesContainer]}>
              <SafeAreaView
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  marginVertical: 10,
                  marginHorizontal: 20
                }}
              >
                {autocompletes.map(() => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    key={shortid.generate()}
                    containerStyle={{}}
                    inputStyle={{
                      borderColor: "transparent",
                      borderBottomColor: "#FFF",
                      width: 250,
                      fontFamily: "FunctionLH"
                    }}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.action.departure")}
                    placeholderColor="#FFF"
                    scrollToInput={ev => {}}
                    handleSelectItem={(item, id) =>
                      this.handleSelectItemStart(item, id)
                    }
                    // onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
                    onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
                    pickerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                    fetchDataUrl={apiUrlWeeCoop+this.state.form.query_start}
                    initialValue={this.state.form.query_start}
                    minimumCharactersCount={2}
                    highlightText
                    valueExtractor={item => item.name}
                    rightContent
                    rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
                  />
                ))}
                <DatePicker
                  date={this.state.datetimeS}
                  mode="datetime"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  hideText={true}
                  showIcon={true}
                  onChange={datetime => {
                    this.setDateTimeS(datetime);
                  }}
                />
              </SafeAreaView>
              <SafeAreaView
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  marginVertical: 10,
                  marginHorizontal: 20
                }}
              >
                {autocompletes.map(() => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    key={shortid.generate()}
                    containerStyle={{}}
                    inputStyle={{
                      borderColor: "transparent",
                      borderBottomColor: "#FFF",
                      width: 250,
                      fontFamily: "FunctionLH"
                    }}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.action.arrival")}
                    placeholderColor="#FFF"
                    scrollToInput={ev => {}}
                    handleSelectItem={(item, id) =>
                      this.handleSelectItemArrival(item, id)
                    }
                    onChange={() => onTripChange()}
                    onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
                    onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
                    pickerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                    fetchDataUrl={apiUrlWeeCoop+this.state.form.query_arrival}
                    initialValue={this.state.form.query_arrival}
                    minimumCharactersCount={2}
                    highlightText
                    valueExtractor={item => item.name}
                    rightContent
                    rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
                  />
                ))}
                <DatePicker
                  date={this.state.datetimeA}
                  mode="datetime"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                  hideText={true}
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  showIcon={true}
                  onChange={datetime => {
                    this.setDateTimeA(datetime);
                    console.log("datetimeA");
                  }}
                />
              </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.collapseScrollView}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleExpanded}>
                <View style={styles.buttonView2}>
                  <View style={styles.touchable2}>
                    <View style={styles.view2}>
                      <Text style={styles.textimg2}>
                        {i18n.t("tripsform.action.plus")}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../assets/images/btn-background.png")}
                      style={styles.tripsimg2}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed} align="center">
                <View style={styles.content}>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.family")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("family", val)}
                  />
                  {/*<TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.product")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("product", val)}
                  />*/}
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.reference")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    type="string"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val =>
                      this.onChangeText("reference", val)
                    }
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Description"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    type="string"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("description", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.weight")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    keyboardType = 'numeric'
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("weight", val)}
                  />
                  {/*<TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.packing")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("packing", val)}
                  />*/}
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.dist")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("dist", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.type")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("type", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.plane")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("plane", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.sit")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("sit", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.price")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    keyboardType = 'numeric'
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("price", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.company")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("company", val)}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={i18n.t("tripsform.item.visit")}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    type="string"
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText("visit", val)}
                  />
                </View>
              </Collapsible>
            </View>
          </View>
          {this.state.form_success == true ? (
            <Text style={[styles.formMessage, styles.formMessageSuccess]}>
              Succesfully...
            </Text>
          ) : null}
          {this.state.form_error.length > 0 ? (
            <Text style={[styles.formMessage, styles.formMessageError]}>
              {this.state.form_error}
            </Text>
          ) : null}
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.touchable}
              onPress={this.handleSubmit}
            >
              <View style={styles.view}>
                <Text style={styles.textimg}>
                  {i18n.t("tripsform.action.add")}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Image
                source={require("../../assets/images/btn-background.png")}
                style={styles.tripsimg}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.touchable}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MyTrips")}
            >
              <View style={styles.view}>
                <Text style={styles.textimg}>
                  {i18n.t("tripsform.action.back")}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Image
                source={require("../../assets/images/btn-background.png")}
                style={styles.tripsimg}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
export default withKeyboardAwareScrollView(Options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed export default **withKeyboardAwareScrollView**(Options) and the bug is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using Expo. This is how I fixed it. If you are using expo
in your app.json add `"android": { "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan", ...(other properties) }`

This is where I found the solution [github issue #2839](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2839)